# Split Git private repo folders into logical repos

Tags: git, github

My company uses Github to store their code. They have a few repos.

Things like

- `WEB` *(repo)*
- `Desktop` *(repo)*

  - `Mac` *(folder)*
  - `Windows`*(folder)*
  - `Linux` *(folder)*
- `Mobile` *(repo)*

  - `Android` *(folder)*
  - `iOS` *(folder)*
  - `Windows`*(folder)*

Recently I made changes to the Mac version, forgot to commit. Then I made changes to the Windows version and when I went to commit, both mac and windows got the same commit description.
Not a big deal. Since the changes were both similar.

Is there a way to break each folder up into its on "logical" repo in the GitHub client?

So if I make changes to `Mobile Android` and `Desktop Linux`, each one has to be committed separately?

*I know what some people are thinking, just create a new repo for each one.*

- `WEB`*(repo)*
- `DESKTOP-Mac`*(repo)*
- `DESKTOP-Windows`*(repo)*
- `DESKTOP-LINUX`*(repo)*
- `MOBILE-Android`*(repo)* etc.etc..

I **can't create new repos** in the root of our git account. The projects must stay in their own repo in their respective folders.

I was hoping someone knew of a way to logically split the projects up.

***How can I make my Github client (or any client) think that the folders are repos?***

Comment: So they don't have a few repos... the have just one repo with many folders?  And you wish the folder were actually repos, right? Sounds like you need to migrate the folders to separate repos

Comment: No. We have 3 repos. They all have sub folders.

Comment: If I understand correctly, you need to move folders to git submodules.
Submodules don't interfere with parent repo, in terms of revision history, commits, etc.